# Call Function of custom Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I'm trying to create a simple framework that has a function that returns "hello *name*" name being a passed argument. Below is the framework and code trying to call it.

Framework:

```
public class Greeter {
    public init () {}
    public static func greet(name: String) -> String {
        return "Hello /(name)."
    }
}
```

Code:

```
import Greeter

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let greetingString: String = Greeter.greet("Bob")
        print(greetingString)
    }
}
```

When I try typing out "*greet("Bob")*", what autocompletes is "*(name: String) -> String greet(self: Greeter)*". And when I manually type "*greet("Bob")*", I get the error: Instance member 'greet' cannot be used on type 'Greeter'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of Greeter class first and then call it's method.

```
let greeter = Greeter()
let greetingString: String = greeter.greet(name: "Bob")
print(greetingString)
```

Update: You don't need `: String` it's redundant here. So you can modify that line to:

```
let greetingString = greeter.greet(name: "Bob")
```

Comment: This works, but is there a way that I can do the same without creating an instance of the class (I've changed the function to be static)? I'm trying to follow Kilo Loco's video below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMYxlkOE35k

Comment: Both are correct. If you make the method static then you could just call `Greeter.greet()`

Comment: Perfect, I just tried that and they both work! thank you so much!